# Show there exists isomorphism $\phi\colon V\to V$ s.t. $\phi(\phi(v))=-v$ for all $v\in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Problem:** Let $ V $ be a vector space over $ \mathbb{F} $ and suppose its dimension is even, dim$V = 2k $. Show there exists an isomorphism $ \phi \colon V \rightarrow V $ s.t. $ \phi(\phi(v)) = -v $ for all $ v \in V$

**My idea:** Most importantly, I know there exists a basis $ \{ v_1,...,v_{2k} \} $ of $ V $ and on the basis I have to define $ \phi(v_i) $ for every $ 1\leq i \leq 2k $ ( and then show it's a bijection and a linear map ). But I'm completely clueless as to how actually define $ \phi(v_i)$ and the fact that we want $ \ker\phi=\{ \vec0\} $ and $\operatorname{im}\phi = V $ ( since we want an isomorphism ) doesn't help me much. Please help.

Comment: Define $\phi$ via $\phi(v_{i})= v_{i+1}$ and $\phi(v_{i+1})= -v_i$ for all $i$ odd.

Comment: Can you please explain how you arrived/thought of that though? I was completely lost.

Comment: $\phi \circ\phi$ is almost an involution, and the simplest involution is the swap of 2 coordinates. Then you have to insert a twist to get the $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to define $\phi$ on a basis $\{v_1,\ldots, v_{2k}\}$ of $V$ and extend it by linearity.
Let $\phi:V\to V$ be given by
$$\begin{array}{l}
\phi(v_{2i-1})= v_{2i}\\
\phi(v_{2i})= -v_{2i-1} \end{array} \qquad i=1,\ldots, k.$$

We then get $\phi(\phi(v_{2i-1}))=\phi(v_{2i})=-v_{2i-1}$ and
$\phi(\phi(v_{2i}))=\phi(-v_{2i-1})=-\phi(v_{2i-1})= -v_{2i}$. Therefore, $\phi \circ \phi= -id_V$.

Comment: Hello, I think you need to edit this because in this way $\phi(v_{2k})=v_{2k+1}$ and that doesn't make any sense. If I were you I'd write $\phi(v_{j})=(-1)^jv_{\sigma(j)}$, where $\sigma(j)$ is the permutation $(1,2)(2,3)\cdots (2k-1,2k)(2k,1)$. It is more neat this way in my opinion :)

Comment: You are right! I wrote the wrong indexes, now it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr|rr|rr}
0&1&0&0&0&0 \\
-1&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline
0&0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&-1&0&0&0 \\ \hline
0&0&0&0&0&1 \\
0&0&0&0&-1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
gives
$$ M^2 = -I$$